# store elements of a vector into another vector

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-c++, vector, 2d-vector

I have a vector of 16997*15931*6 elements. You know this is the different bands of a raster that have been read by RasterIO function of the GDAL library.Now I want to store the elements into a 2d vector that have six elements(rows) and each row will contain 16997*15931 elements. I know that I can have a loop iterating 16997*15931*6 and evaluate i%6:

```
vector<vector<unsigned char> > bands(6,vector<unsigned char>)
for(i=0;i<(6*16997*15931);i++)
   bands[i%6].pushback(data.at(i));
```

But since I'm working with high resolution .tiff images, I need codes with high performance. so any faster algorithm will be welcomed.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should compile with maximum optimization and measure the performance of the current code. It can also depend on the processor you use.

If you really must change it, I suggest that you define a struct of 6 chars, and do struct assignment. You will have a vector of structs, and then your loop can be like

```
for (i = 0; i < 16997*15931; i++)
    something.pushback(data.at(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand where the algorithm is slow before you can optimize it. Some suggestions:

- call something.push_back(data[i]); instead of calling .at(); The operator doesn't check the index bounds, but at(), so is therefore slightly faster
- Resize the vectors before the loops start. As it is, the vector will be resized as it grows, which will allocate, copy, free repeatedly through the loop. These can be expensive operations, and as you know the size before you start, pre-allocating can avoid the overhead
- Eliminating the i%6 I side the loop *may* help by avoiding a relatively expensive division over and over